# Is it necessary to enable developing mode in magento 2 while update magento version

Tags: magento2, upgrade

**I am going to update magento 2.0.1 to 2.1.6 so it is necessary to enable developing mode while doing this?**

Comment: It will be good practice. But it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is necessary.

To upgrade Magento to follow these steps:

1. Put your store in maintenance mode.

   ```
   php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento maintenance:enable
   ```

(it only applies if you set the Magento root directory to /pub)

2. Upgrade using the command line.

   ```
   composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 --no-update
   ```
3. Manually clear var subdirectories

   ```
   rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
   rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
   rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/generation/*
   ```
4. Update the database schema and data:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```
5. Remove maintenance mode

   ```
   php bin/magento maintenance:disable
   ```

Further details can be found in the [official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html).

Make sure you test all these changes in a separated environment and only when you sure everything is fine, deploy those to production.